Как настроить Nginx что бы url в адресной строке открывался без указания порта на локальной машине
Открывается только вот так http://autoservis.loc:84/ Как сделать что бы открывался так http://autoservis.loc/. 80, 8081, 8080 уже заняты другим контейнером. Вот конфигурационные файлы докера.
 webserver:
    build:
      context: nginx
    volumes:
      - ../../wadossnik/site:/site
      - ../../wadossnik/docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "84:80"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm

default.conf:
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name autoservis.loc;

     root /site/public_html;
     index index.php index.html;

     client_max_body_size 128m;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization' always;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

     location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

     error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка, приведя его в человеческий вид, а затем и сам вопрос сформулируйте, описав, что же вам требуется, и что именно происходит не так, как вы ожидаете.

nginx тут не при чем, порт показывает сам браузер, и если порт 80 для http, то он не показывается, так же 443 порт не показывается для https. я бы предложил поставить nginx слушать порт 80 или 443 и проксить запросы уже к твоему приложению например на 8000 порте
